# How to run a python script in node js server?

Tags: python, node.js, server, anaconda

I want to run a python script on my node js server. I have installed python with anaconda. Here is my first approach:

```
function runPy() {
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');

    const pyprog = spawn('python', ['--version']);

    pyprog.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(`stoud: ${data}`);
    });

    pyprog.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    pyprog.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
}
runPy();
```

And this is the error I get: 
stderr: Python was not found; run witho
stderr: ut arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
child process exited with code 9009
Then I tried creating an env with conda, but I get another error:

```
function runPy() {
    const { spawn } = require('child_process');

    const pythonScript = 'faceMorph.py';
    const envName = 'test';
    const command = `conda run -n ${envName} python ${pythonScript}`;
    const pyprog = spawn(command);

    pyprog.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(`stoud: ${data}`);
    });

    pyprog.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    pyprog.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
}
runPy();
```

node:events:353
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn conda run -n test python faceMorph.py ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:276:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn conda run -n test python faceMorph.py',
path: 'conda run -n test python faceMorph.py',
spawnargs: []
}

Comment: Most likely python is not listed in your PATH env. Use full path of python executable instead. If you are on linux, find it under /usr/bin (or use `whereis python` command to locate) and replace 'python' command with /usr/bin/python3.